# Laravel / Lumen: Select all starting with

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, lumen

I'm figuring out how to work with Lumen (a stripped Laravel framework) and am a bit stuck on the ORM / query builder.

I have the following function, which currently isn't working, and want it to display all the users starting with the letter 'b'.

```
public function getUsers()
{ 
    $users = User::where('name', 'b%')->get();
    return response()->json($users);
}
```

How do I approach this? I'm so used to plain SQL that I'm confused about this query builder. So how do I fetch all the users starting with the letter 'b'?

Thank you for taking the time to read and hopefully answer my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `where` method with `like`:

```
$users = User::where('name', 'like', 'b%')->get();
```

Comment: I should've known, thank you!